# Not able to extract values from Bootstrap dropdown to my calculation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying out Bootstrap to style my dropdowns and I want to make a small calculation based on the values selected from two dropdowns. Basically, you're going to choose the number of people going on a boat. All the boats have fixed prices, so the more you are on one boat, the cheaper it gets for each person. But there are different boats available for different amount of people. The number of people are divided into three groups; 5-7, 8-9 and 10-11 persons.

Here's my two dropdowns:

```
<select id="pickpersons" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="100%" title="Välj antal">
    <option value="5">5 personer</option>
    <option value="6">6 personer</option>
    <option value="7" data-subtext="(mer prisvärt)">7 personer</option>
    <option value="8">8 personer</option>
    <option value="9" data-subtext="(mer prisvärt)">9 personer</option>
    <option value="10">10 personer</option>
    <option value="11" data-subtext="(mer prisvärt)">11 personer</option>
</select>
<select id="pickboat" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="100%" data-header="Välj båt">
    <option value="oceanis40" data-price="8999">Oceanis 40</option>
    <option value="bavaria38" data-price="8699">Bavaria 38</option>
    <option value="hanse370" data-price="8799">Hanse 370</option>
    <option value="sunodyssey42" data-price="9699">Sun Odyssey 42</option>
</select>
```

So I want to extract the number of people from the first dropdown and have that value multiplied with the price from the boat (defined in the 2nd dropdown's data-price attribute) and have that number divided by the maximum number of persons per price group (7, 9 or 11).

```
var pickboat;
var pickedpersons = $('#pickpersons').val();
var boatprice = $('#pickboat').data('price');

if (pickedpersons === 5 || pickedpersons === 6 || pickedpersons === 7) {
    pickboat = "7";
} else if (pickedpersons === 8 || pickedpersons === 9) {
    pickboat = "9";
} else if (pickedpersons === 10 || pickedpersons === 11) {
    pickboat = "11";
};

var price = (boatprice*pickedpersons)/pickboat;

console.log(price);
```

This is my attempt for a jQuery solution, but I'm not being able to extract the numbers correctly. Tried to look through the Bootstrap manual and see if I missed anything, but I couldn't find out what.

Got any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has nothing at all to do with Bootstrap. It's just a visual design framework. Can you call `console.log(pickboat, pickedpersons, boatprice);` and make sure they're returning the right values?

Comment: undefined "5" undefined

Comment: So at the very least, boatprice is not returning anything. Try `$('#pickboat option:selected').data('price')` instead. That'll pull the data-price attribute on the currently selected option.

Answer (score 1):

here is my try at solution-->

> ```
> var pickboat;
> var pickedpersons = parseInt($('#pickpersons').val());
> var boatprice = $('#pickboat option:selected').data('price');
> alert(pickedpersons);alert(boatprice);
> if (pickedpersons === 5 || pickedpersons === 6 || pickedpersons ===  7) 
> {
>     pickboat = "7";
> } else if (pickedpersons === 8 || pickedpersons === 9) {
>     pickboat = "9";
> } else if (pickedpersons === 10 || pickedpersons === 11) {
>     pickboat = "11";
> };
> var price = (boatprice*pickedpersons)/pickboat;
> alert(price);
> ```

Comment: Horray, I'm getting values! (Using console.log(pickboat, pickedpersons, boatprice); from Olly's suggestion.)

It doesn't seem to pick the right one, though. Whatever I choose from the dropdowns, I get the same numbers; 7 5 8999. I've tried to the console.log() inside this:

http://pastebin.com/80zdaptw